# how to fill in konvajs path picture?

Tags: javascript, svg, path, konvajs

I faced a problem overlaying pictures on the way in the framework konvajs. How can this be done? Was thoughts like that to invert the path and loop it over and impose another path. I have to run a man on the way, and under the nm background of this way. At the moment there is such a enter code here

```js
var stage = new Konva.Stage({
    container: 'myCanvas',
    width: document.querySelector('#myCanvas').clientWidth,
    height: document.querySelector('#myCanvas').clientHeight
    });

var layer = new Konva.Layer();

var imageObjT2 = new Image();
    imageObjT2.onload = function() {
      var path2 = new Konva.Path({
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        data: 'M 56 336 Q 135 403 209 346 C 221.5 300.5 271.5 300.5 284 255 Q 356 193 421 282 Q 447 300.5 483 346 Q 551 358 599 369 C 680 345 730 345 751 371',
        stroke: 'green',
      });

      path2.fillPatternImage(imageObjT2);
      layer.add(path2);
      stage.add(layer);

    };
imageObjT2.src = 'https://opengameart.org/sites/default/files/tileable-grass_clover_tt7010116-sample_1.png';
```

```css
#myCanvas {
    width: 800px;
    height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myCanvas"></div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/konva@3.4.1/konva.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You can't use fill for such a path. It is not closed. It just draws a line.